# re.sub() gives Nameerror when no match

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to search and replace rows of texts from a csv file, and I keep getting errors from it if re.sub() can't find any matches.

Say if the text in a row is

```
text = "a00123 一二三四五"
```

And my codes are

```
import re
html = "www.abcdefg.com/"
text = "a00123 一二三四五"
namelist_raw = re.sub(r'([a-z])00(\d{3})',r'\1-\2',text)
p = re.findall(r'\w',namelist_raw)
if p:
  q = re.findall(r'([a-z]-\d{3})',namelist_raw)
  for namelist in q:
    print(namelist)
else:
  namelist = "failed"

link = html + namelist
print(link)
```

so for this i should be getting a result of

```
www.abcdefg.com/a-123
```

so that's no problem. 
but if the text is something like this,

```
text = "asdfdsdfd123 一二三四五"
```

I'll get Nameerror saying name 'namelist' is not defined
Why is that? I thought at the if else statement I've already wrote if anything else, namelist is "failed"

[my code](https://repl.it/@thefatboy123/ExcitableUnderstatedLesson)

Comment: This code does not compile, are you sure you shared all relevant lines?

Comment: ooops. @WiktorStribiżew sorry forgot to type in other lines

Comment: I get `www.abcdefg.com/a-123`, see https://ideone.com/CUMlIX

Comment: yes, but if you replace the text with "asdfdsdfd123 一二三四五", you'll get an error saying name 'namelist' is not defined  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/iOiRGR

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. It worked, but why won't my code return "www.abcdefg.com/failed" when there's no match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `p = re.findall(r'\w',namelist_raw)` is extracting every word char from a string, and later, you only extract the values from the string if there were matches. You do not need that check.

Next, `namelist` is only populated if there is a match for `[a-z]-\d{3}`, but if there is no match, you do not get it populated. You need to account for that scenario, too.

Use

```
import re
html = "www.abcdefg.com/"
text = "a00123 一二三四五"
p = re.findall(r'([a-z])00(\d{3})', text)  # Extract a list of tuples
namelist = []                              # Init the list
for letter, number in p:                  
  namelist.append(f"{letter}-{number}")    # Populate namelist with formatted tuple values

if len(namelist):                          # If there was a match
  namelist = "/".join(namelist)            # Create a string by joining namelist items with /
else:
  namelist = "failed"                      # Else, assign failed to the namelist

link = html + namelist
print(link)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/iOiRGR).